# Unexpected compiler behavior when using stdbool.h

Tags: c

here is my code

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "func.h"

int main () {
  int counts = 10;
  printf("Expected: %lF and rcount %lF,%lF\n",
          counts * 30* 0.156, rcount(0,30), rcount(30,0));

  return 0;
}
```

and here is my simplified func.h

```
#ifndef FUNC_INCLUDED
#define FUNC_INCLUDED

float rcount(int m, int n);

#endif
```

and finally here my func.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "func.h"

double rcount(int m, int n) {
  double series1 = ((double)m/2)*(10+(double)m*10)/20;
  double series2 = ((double)n/2)*(10+(double)n*10)/20;
  return (series2 > series1) ? series2-series1 : series1-series2;
}
```

Now, If I execute, I get random values for `rcount()`, whilst if I remove `#include<stdbool.h>` from the main, I get the right values.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see how that can make any difference.  How do you build it?  Did you notice you have a mismatch in your prototype and implementation of `rcount`?

Comment: the fact is that i could also do rcount("","","","") and it doesnt give me a syntax error :/

Comment: I'll reiterate, then.  How do you build it?  I copied & pasted this exact code and it works fine here with and without `stdbool.h`.

Comment: try with stdbool, i am using gcc on mac: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2

Comment: As I just said, I tried both ways and I get consistent results.  I was using clang, but I'll try again with gcc.  Edit:  exactly the same results. Once more - how do you build it?

Comment: what do you mean for how do you build it ? gcc main.c func.c

Comment: Same here and it works fine.  There must be something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 1):

As @Carl Norum said, "There must be something you're not telling us" is very telling.

The rcount() calls are the printf() statement is returning its double type, but printf() is expecting a float because of the prototype or an int if the prototype was not seen. In either case, printf() presents wrong data.

Try 3 things: 1) Use a different define other than FUNC_INCLUDED, it is *slightly* possible stdbool.h is using that macro.  2) change your prototype and implementation to return the same type, preferable double. 3) make a redundant copy of the rcount() prototype directly before main().

```
extern double rcount(int m, int n);
```

The use/lack of stdbool.h is a red herring.  With/without it, your compilation is doing using some different file, option, etc. (Unless its the FUNC_INCLUDED)

Comment: Another indication that something isn't being communicated correctly: `func.c` should fail to compile because the type of `rcount()` from the prototype in `func.h` doesn't match the type of `rcount()` defined in `func.c`.